# Ignored tags - still in list

Tags: support

Recently I started using the Ignored Tags feature, obviously to see only the questions that I might be interested in. However, the questions with those ignored tags still show show up in the list of questions. Dimmed, but still...

Is it possible to change that behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

On your user profile, under preferences, check the "hide ignored tags" option and that should do it for you. Though this is client side, so odd gaps may appear.

Quick link to your preferences: https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/13714

Comment: Ah... I missed that one, Joanne. Thanks!

Comment: @Ron - Cheers, it's a little obscure I think.

Comment: I did not expect it be a preference in the profile. To me it seems more logical to set the ignored tags and immediately experience the effect. Matter of design choice, I guess. I prefer less clicks, but anyway, now it´s set and forget :-)